# how do I handle ‘cannot reference SB without a symbol’ error with golang Assembly On Windows?

Tags: go, assembly, x86

when I call asm using golang, i countered a problem on Windows.

here is in a  cpuid_amd64.go file

```
func cpuid_low(arg1, arg2 uint32) (eax, ebx, ecx, edx uint32)
```

and the  definition

```
#include "textflag.h"

// func cpuid_low(arg1, arg2 uint32) (eax, ebx, ecx, edx uint32)
TEXT ·cpuid_low(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-24
    MOVL arg1+0(FP), AX
    MOVL arg2+4(FP), CX
    CPUID
    MOVL AX, eax+8(FP)
    MOVL BX, ebx+12(FP)
    MOVL CX, ecx+16(FP)
    MOVL DX, edx+20(FP)
    RET
```

on Windows, an error message was reported:

```
info\cpuidlow_amd64.s:4: cannot reference SB without a symbol
asm: assembly of info\cpuidlow_amd64.s failed
```

There is an underscore right below the '· 'character, which displays as:
`identifier expected, got ·`

[image]

Comment: That's not an ASCII `.` character, it's `·` UTF8 `c2 b7`.  Are you sure that's what you want?  I don't know Go's asm syntax very well.

Comment: It also seems strange that you have this in a file called `amd64`, but you're loading two adjacent 4-byte chunks of stack space.  That would mean that both input args were packed together into one 8-byte stack slot.  Also, you're not saving/restoring RBX around this function; it's call-preserved in all normal calling conventions, probably also Go's weird convention (where args are returned by value on the stack)

Comment: @PeterCordes That is correct for Go assembly.

Comment: This code compiles for me.  Make sure the encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: @PeterCordes  On Linux, everything works fine.  But in Windows, the error I've described occurs.

Comment: @fuz Did you test successfully on Windows?  I compiled the code with goland, and failed

Comment: @tfxidian Unfortunately I do not have access to a Windows machine.  Consider filing a bug report with the Go project.

Comment: How did you test the code on the two?  Did you transfer the files?  Or did you just copy-paste into a text editor?  This might well be an encoding problem.

Comment: I 'new' (create) a .go/.s file with goland, and copy the code into the file. and I also tried to copy the files compiled successfully On Linux

Comment: @tfxidian Very interesting.  I cannot tell what the problem is.  Please make sure you are actually compiling the correct version of the code and please make sure that the encoding is correct.  For example, check with a separate editor like Notepad++.

Comment: @fuz I came up with an indirect solution: I compiled and generated.exe file under Linux platform through cross-compilation, which ran successfully under Windows platform.